# Every R-automorphism of $U_2(R)$ is inner

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with this problem (not homework, just for practice purposes):

Let R be a commutative ring with identity and define $U_2(R)$ = $\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & c
\end{bmatrix} \mid a,b,c\in R\} $. Prove that every R-automorphism of $U_2(R)$ is inner.

I do understand the definition of inner automorphisms, but I'm usually lost when I'm given the condition that "**all** automorphisms are inner". How do I prove that every automorphism of a group is in the form of conjugation if I don't know what each automorphism exactly is?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: " if I don't know what their definitions are?" why don't you look up the definition?

Comment: Is $U_2(R)$ a group with respect to matrix multiplication?  If so, then you need to require that $a, c$ are units in $R$.  Otherwise not every element has an inverse.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sorry for the confusion (and I just edited my question). I do know the definition of an automorphism, but I don't know how to show that every automorphism is inner "if I don't know what [this] automorphism exactly is".

Comment: @D_S The problem does not require a, c to be units, so I assume this is just a ring rather than a group under multiplication.